# Parse file images not loading to PFTableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemImage: PFImageView!

override func tableView(tableView: (UITableView), cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!), object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PFTableViewCell") as! ItemViewCell!

    let items = object as! Items

    let thumbnail = items.valueForKey("itemImage") as! PFFile!
    cell.itemImage?.file = thumbnail

    return cell
}
```

When I run this, the PFTableViewController just loads infinitely.

Commenting out:

cell.itemImage?.file = thumbnail

Will load the TVC but there are no images loaded. I made every connection/outlet necessary for this to function, in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given will throw an error if you are trying to show the image in UIImageView within a cell in tableView since you have only assigned it an instance of UIImage.

To fix this, you will need to assign the UIImageView outlet to .image
as shown below in the line;

```
cell.itemImage.image = image
```

Full solution that works in my test project is below;

```
if let pic = items.objectForKey("itemImage") as? PFFile
{
   pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(
   { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

       if((error) == nil && data != nil)
       {
           if let image = UIImage(data: data!) 
           { 
               cell.itemImage.image = image 
           }
       }                 
           else { NSLog("Error loading profile image in cell") }
       }
})
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments of the previous post you will also need to reload the tableView before the data will display as the tableView almost always loads before the image in this example.

You can do this by adding;

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

At the end of your function

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call getDataInBackground to fetch the actual PFFile data, then you can create a UIImage from the NSData object you get back from your query.

```
if let pic = items.objectForKey("itemImage") as? PFFile
{
   pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(
   { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

       if((error) == nil && data != nil)
       {
           if let image = UIImage(data: data!) 
           { 
               cell.itemImage = image }
           }                 
           else { NSLog("Error loading profile image in cell") }
       }
})
```

This is assuming your UITableViewCell subclass has a property "itemImage".

Comment: You will still need to reload the tableview with the index path for the cell you are loading the image, otherwise it won't show even if its downloaded